# Does the standalone "Red Dead Redemption: Undead Nightmare" include the original game?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I'm considering buying Red Dead Redemption: Undead Nightmare. I found the disc for cheap, but I already own the original Red Dead Redemption.

Does Undead Nightmare include all the content from the originally released Red Dead Redemption?  Or is it **just** the DLC and not the original storyline?  I found places that say what it adds, and that it includes this and other DLC.  But nothing explicitly says whether it includes the **original** disc of content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not include the original game.

It includes the 3 released DLC packs:

- Legends & Killers
- Liars & Cheats
- Undead Nightmare

However, you can play the Undead Nightmare disc standalone without purchasing the original game.